# errors while running the shell script

Tags: shell

```
WARNING: error instantiating 'java.util.logging.FileHandler,' referenced by handlers, class not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.logging.FileHandler,
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.util.logging.LogManager.locateClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.util.logging.LogManager.createInstance(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at vists.VisTS.main(VisTS.java:64)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.util.logging.Logger.addHandler(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at vists.VisTS.main(VisTS.java:64)
./SampleStartVisTsData.sh: line 5: cd..: command not found
```

I am unable to find out the errors that I got while running the batch file

The following is the shellscript:

```
cd ../../classes
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:../vismine.jar:../mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar
java -Xm500m vists.VisTS ../ConfigFiles/dataCenterMySQL-log.xml
cd..
```

Help needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have cd.. on line 5 when you should have cd .. (Note the spaces)

Comment: That's one of the problems, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

One of the errors is the '`cd..`' command, which would need a space in it '`cd ..`' if it were not redundant anyway.  Your script changes directory to run Java in the correct place, but there's no need to change directory again before exiting - this is Linux and not DOS (where it was necessary; and your exiting `cd` does not return you to where you started).

It seems odd to change to the classes directory and then expect to find jar files in the directory above - are you sure that's right?

It would probably be sensible to ensure that the first `cd` works, too:

```
error(){
    echo "$@" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
cd ../../classes || exit 1
[ -r ../vismine.jar ] || error "did not find vismine.jar"
[ -r ../mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar ] ||
    error "did not find mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar"
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:../vismine.jar:../mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar
java -Xm500m vists.VisTS ../ConfigFiles/dataCenterMySQL-log.xml
```

In principle, you could export CLASSPATH for the Java command alone by writing:

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:../vismine.jar:../mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar \
java -Xm500m vists.VisTS ../ConfigFiles/dataCenterMySQL-log.xml
```

However, it isn't worth it this time since it would spread over two lines of code anyway.